# Overriding exec-maven-plugin with exec.mainClass

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin

I have started a new maven project and configured `exec-maven-plugin` to set a default `mainClass`, and I can execute using

```
mvn exec:java -q
Hello World!
```

However if I try to specify a different mainClass on the command line, this seems to get ignored:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.jamesmcguigan.kdt.App2" -q
Hello World!
```

The above line works if I comment out the `exec-maven-plugin` section from the pom.xml, but it would be nice to set the default in the `pom.xml` for `maven exec:java` and have a way of overriding this on the cli for `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.jamesmcguigan.kdt.App2"`.

Or am I missing something else here?

### Files

pom.xml

```
  <build>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.jamesmcguigan.kdt.App</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

src/main/java/com/jamesmcguigan/kdt/App.java

```
package com.jamesmcguigan.kdt;
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

src/main/java/com/jamesmcguigan/kdt/App2.java

```
package com.jamesmcguigan.kdt;
public class App2 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World 2!" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a property, i.e.:

```
<properties>
        ...
        <main.class>com.jamesmcguigan.kdt.App</main.class>
</properties>
...
<configuration>
         <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
</configuration>
```

And then:
`mvn exec:java -Dmain.class="com.jamesmcguigan.kdt.App2" -q`

Comment: Thank you, this works. It is also possible to use `<exec.mainClass>` as the variable name for backwards compatibility. And note to self: don't forget to use `mvn compile exec:java` when encountering `ClassNotFoundError`

Comment: Is this a bug of Maven Exec Plugin? The -Dexec.mainClass property should work as per https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html. Same behavior with 1.6.0 and 3.0.0. It seems the plugin's configuration in the pom.xml overrides command line properties which should not happen.

Answer (score 1):

To override main class and args, e.g.:

```xml
<project>
    ...
    <properties>
        <!-- default values -->
        <mainClass>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}.App</mainClass>
        <mainArgs/>
    </properties>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    <commandlineArgs>${mainArgs}</commandlineArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

To execute overrides:

```
mvn compile exec:java -DmainClass=org.example.Main -DmainArgs="arg1 arg2"
```